# Data too long for column 'column_name' at row 1

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

We recently moved a mySQL database from AIX( yeah !that old) to windows virtual server environment.
The application which access this database is in c#.net.
The application is trying to insert data through Stored procedure.The error is thrown, when it trying to insert a char ( basically a "Y" or a "N") to a column of datatype Char(1) on mysql.
The error , it throws is "Data too long for column column_name at row1"
I checked inserting data

1. from MySQl workbench- It works fine
2. from the c# application with out going through the stored procedure(basia      insert statement)- it works fine.

   3.Only when it inserts through SP, it throws error.

   4.I tried changing from Char(1) to char(5)- throws the same error

Well, all this stored procedure worked perfectly fine in AIX world. Changing to non_strict_mode on my.ini file is not an option here.
Most of all the other inserts is going into database fine.
Please let me know, how else, can I test insert and find a solution.

Comment: Character set differences (single vs multi-byte) may cause such issues. Stored proc's character set is fixed when it is compiled - unless explicitly provided for the string parameters. Check out `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES.CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT` to determine the character set used by the stored proc

Comment: Table information shows that the character set of the fields are utf8. Should this be explicitly stated in the c# code?

Comment: The real question is: what is the character field of the data producing the  error

Comment: It was very simple fix. The order of inserting the parameters from c# .net code was slightly different from the order the Stored procedure was accepting it. i simply re ordered the parameters, in c# code, and Tada , it was done! Never thought it that way. Thank for all the help!